# ActionCable Socket Without Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I see here in [the docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#server-side-components) that in order for ActionCable to establish a WebSocket connection with the client, the client has to authenticate with the server.

Is there any way to use ActionCable to establish a WebSocket connection with a client *without* the client authenticating with Rails?

Comment: Sure. The linked example shows a simple setup using authenticated users to both secure and identify a connection, since it is assumed any non-trivial use would need something like it. But, how or if you implement authentication is up to you. if you don't override `connect` ActionCable will still establish a connection.

Comment: action-cable does not relative to (or require) authentication at all, it's connected by default and if you want to reject the connection, you have to do manual (on connection or channel), for example, in the linked example, the only method that will prevent the connection is established is  [reject_unauthorized_connection](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionCable/Connection/Authorization.html#method-i-reject_unauthorized_connection), so if you comment that method, the connection will be established no matter user authenticated or not.