# Rails ActionCable: Is there a way to skip connection authentication for specific channels?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

So I've looked at [ActionCable Socket Without Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68695742/actioncable-socket-without-authentication) which doesn't quite fit my usecase.

I have a standard connection class in `Rails 7.0.3`:

```rb
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      # Extract and authenticate connection request from JWT token
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
    end
    # Ommited
    ......
  end
end
```

and a bunch of channels which get access to the authenticated user. For example a `UserChannel`

```rb
class UserChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stop_all_streams
    stream_for "user_#{current_user.id}_verify_email"
  end  
end
```

In order to establish a connection, on the client:

```js
// Token is a JWT token issued by the server
new WebSocket(`ws://localhost:3000/cable?token=${token}`)
```

Now my question is, in some instances, I'd like to subscribe to channels where having access to an authenticated user isn't possible. For example, a forgot password channel:

```rb
class ForgotPasswordChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stop_all_streams
    stream_for "forgot_password_channel"
  end
end
```

Having the forgot password channel is important because it provides a mechanism to notify clients that the forgot password link sent to a users email has been verified and you can proceed to show them a reset password screen. My other option is deep linking as the client is a mobile app which means normal HTML views don't make the cut here(this is highly desirable in my case).

Is there a way to skip authentication for this a particular channel? Something like:

```rb
class ForgotPasswordChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  # Or something similar?
  skip_before_all :connect

  def subscribed
    stop_all_streams
    stream_for "forgot_password_channel"
  end
end
```

Tried looking at the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#more-complete-examples) but no help. Any ideas or help would be appreciated as I really want to avoid deep linking or creating an HTML page for users to reset their password.